# angularjs ng-init replacement in angular 2 or 4

Tags: angular

angularjs ng-init alternative in angular 2 or 4.

i written sample code of angularjs in below it working correctly but i want to same logic in angular 2 or 4.

calling the method via html if the condition is true.

**sample.controller.js**

```
$scope.showDiv = true;

$scope.callFunction = function() {
        console.log("myFunction");
};
```

**sample.html**

```
<div ng-if="showDiv">
    <div ng-init="callFunction()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-init is documented as "you should never use ng-init" in AngularJS. So, why would there be a replacement?

Comment: ng-init is obsolete, but that aside, where is your ng-init anyways ?

Comment: You can use ngOnInit in your TypeScript component. https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Comment: only thing you can do is create a directive and call it as a function.